# Manipulating tensorial terms with xAct, ToCanonical is not perfoming well

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors, xact

I am trying to calculate perturbations of some complicated Lagrangians. Using xAct and more specifically `VarD` to perform the perturbations the expressions become annoyingly long, even after performing `ToCanonical` and `Simplify`, respectively `Simplification`. I have figured out that one of the main issues seems to be the fact that it seems to be unable to figure out the identity between different terms.

Example: Using the Lagrangian: `L1=-(1/4) Sqrt[-Detmetric[]]  F[-a, -b]   F[a, b]` I do the following:

`L1pert = ExpandPerturbation[Perturbation[L1 /. F2A]] // NoScalar //  ContractMetric // ToCanonical // Simplify // Scalar`

`L1pert = First[L1pert] Last[L1pert]`

where F2A is a rule transforming `F[-a,-b]` into `CD[-a][A[-b]]-CD[-b][A[-a]]`.

Then

`EOMg1 = VarD[\[Delta]g[LI[1], a, b], CD][L1pert] /.  delta[-LI[1], LI[1]] -> 1 // ContractMetric // ToCanonical //  Simplify`

and finally

`EOMg1 = Collect[EOMg1, metric[__], Simplify]`

yields the result:

$$\tfrac{1}{2} (\nabla_{a}A^{c} \nabla_{b}A_{c} -  \nabla_{b}A_{c} \nabla^{c}A_{a} + \nabla_{c}A_{b} \nabla^{c}A_{a} -  \nabla_{a}A_{c} \nabla^{c}A_{b}) + \tfrac{1}{4} g_{ab} (\nabla_{c}A_{d} -  \nabla_{d}A_{c}) \nabla^{d}A^{c}$$

This expression can be further simplified but it seems not to do so. Even explicitly telling to collect terms of the form `CD[_][ A[_]]` does not seem to collect the terms `CD[-b][ A[-c]]` that can be seen right at the beginning of the expression.

I wonder if the problem is related to internal use of dummy indicies and thus mathematica/xAct not seeing certain obvious ways of group stuff together. More explicitly, it seems to have trouble, when the identical terms are not in the same postion on the tensorial term or of they are related by switching up/down dummy indices. Both issues are presented in the example.

I am aware that in this short example it is not really an issue. It turns into one for more involved calculations that have many terms cancelling each other out in reality but not being recognized and thus making it a huge mess (up to 11 pages for a single expression).

Code for reference:

```
<<xAct`ExpressionManipulation`
<<xAct`xCore`
<<xAct`xPerm`
<<xAct`xTensor` 
<<xAct`xCoba`
<<xAct`xPert`

$PrePrint=ScreenDollarIndices

$CovDFormat="Prefix"

DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}]

DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs->"g"]

DefTensor[A[-a], M]

DefTensor[F[-a, -b], M, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]

F2A=MakeRule[{F[-a, -b], CD[-a][A[-b]]-CD[-b][A[-a]]},
MetricOn->All, ContractMetrics-> True]

L1=Sqrt[-Detmetric[]](-1/4F[-a, -b]×F[a, b])

DefMetricPerturbation[metric, δg]

DefTensorPerturbation[δA[LI["order"], -a], A[-a], {M}]

L1pert=
ExpandPerturbation[Perturbation[L1/.F2A]]//NoScalar//ContractMetric//ToCanonical//
Simplify//Scalar
L1pert=First[L1pert]×Last[L1pert]

EOMg1=VarD[δg[LI[1], a, b], CD][L1pert]/.delta[-LI[1], LI[1]]->1//ContractMetric//
ToCanonical

EOMg1=Collect[EOMg1, metric[__], Simplify]
```

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.SE]!  Can you edit your question to provide a working sample of code (with initializations, definitions, etc.)?  Folks are more likely to help if they have a version of your code that they can copy, paste, and modify.